# return false not preventing click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery to prevent click , but its not working , why ?

**HTML**

```
<a href="page.htm?action=addtofav&amp;id=556" class="fav-auto">
<div class="favno button-com color">Favorite</div></a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

        $(document).on("click","a.fav-auto",function(e) {
           $.get($(this).attr("href"),function(fav-lin) {
              var fav-pos = $(fav-lin).find('.fav-mess-in');
              var fav-pis2 = $(this).attr("href");
              $('fav-mess').empty();
              $('fav-mess').append(fav-pos);
              $('fav-mess').append(fav-pos2);
           });
              return false;
          });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return false` does work perfectly, but you have some syntax errors in your code.

First, I think that `$('fav-mess')` should be either a *class* `$('.fav-mess')`, or *id* `$('#fav-mess')` selector, not a *tag* selector.

Next, You have to change `fav-pos`, `fav-pos2` and `fav-lin` variables.
You **cannot** use `-` (minus) operator in variable declaration - this is a syntax error (javascript interpretes them as math operation : `fav`*minus*`pos`):

```
var fav-pos = $(fav-lin).find('.fav-mess-in');
var fav-pos2 = $(this).attr("href");
```

Replace them to something like this (used class on `'fav-mess'` element since I'm not sure what you're selecting):

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"),function(fav_lin) {
    var fav_pos = $(fav_lin).find('.fav-mess-in');
    var fav_pos2 = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.fav-mess').empty();
    $('.fav-mess').append(fav_pos);
    $('.fav-mess').append(fav_pos2);
});
```

---

PS. Use [chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/) whenever you can, so that you don't unnecessarily traverse the DOM multiple times for a single element:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"),function(fav_lin) {
    var fav_pos = $(fav_lin).find('.fav-mess-in');
    var fav_pos2 = $(this).attr("href");
    // chain the element manipulation:
    $('.fav-mess').empty().append(fav_pos).append(fav_pos2);
});
```

Comment: so i cant use "-" in variables :) .. thank you very much .. been like 3 hours trying and searching to solve that :/ ... thanks